# Explanation of triangle inequality of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

Exactly what does the following inequality signify:

$||z1|-|z2||≤|z1-z2|≤|z1|+|z2|$

How can we take the modulus(defined for a complex number)of real numbers as is given by $||z1|-|z2||$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we don't know which of $|z_1|$ and $|z_2|$ is larger, to get their difference we take the absolute value $||z_1| - |z_2||$.

If e.g. $|z_1| = 3$ and $|z_2| = 2$ then the distance between $z_1$ and $z_2$ is at most 2+3=5 (if they point in opposite directions) and at least 3-2=1 (if they pint in the same direction.)

Comment: Oh, so they mean the absolute value. Alright, thanks :)

Comment: Note that the absolute value of a real number is just its modulus as a complex number.

Comment: Oh, yeah! That cleared it right up!